# How to use setFriendlyName() for a specific device from native android in IBM Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am able to create a useridentity in mobilefirst using custom authenticator.

**But I want to add a friendly name in the devices section of operational console, how do I add Friendlyname from android native code.**

Do I need to do it from adapter or in the app if I am using native android code. Because I can see something for js client side but nothing for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Friendly Name API has been added in the latest version of MFP 7.1(16-Nov-2016 release).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the device's friendly-name using the `WL.Device.setFriendlyName` API method.

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/introduction-to-mobilefirst-platform-operations-console/#devices
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html

Comment: I have seen these links, the problem is the second link is client side js API doc. I am working on Native android... how do I use it in android code I tried using WLClient.getWlDevice. But it doesn't have anything saying setFriendlyName .